# How to reset color settings of Ubuntu on Windows 10 (WSL)?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've played around with [colortool.exe](https://github.com/Microsoft/console/tree/master/tools/ColorTool) utility to change color scheme of terminal, then reset colors to their defaults, but now Ubuntu's Bash shows some weird coloring:

[image]

Comment: Try the legacy one https://github.com/Microsoft/console/blob/master/tools/ColorTool/schemes/cmd-legacy.ini

Answer (score 6):

In regedit, just delete HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\**something_with_ubuntu_in_the_name**

Then, if you want to use some auto customization with PowerShell scripts (or another tools), right click in Ubuntu bash title bar and select "Properties" and "OK" to let Ubuntu bash recreate default regedit settings, so your auto customization tools can find and modify these default settings.

Comment: I don't see this key in 1809

Comment: Probably because you haven't set any custom properties for "Ubuntu Bash" like I said above. I'm with Windows 1809 too and after change any property (font size, color, etc)  you should see something like:

C:_Program Files_WindowsApps_CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_1804.2018.817.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc_ubuntu.exe